# How do I uninstall FaceTime for macOS?

Tags: terminal, facetime, macos

I would like to completely uninstall FaceTime for macOS.

Dragging and dropping the icon into the Trash gives me this error message:

> “FaceTime” can’t be modified or deleted because it’s required by
>   macOS.

Running this command:

```bsh
$ sudo rm -rf FaceTime.app/
```

Gives me a series of:

> Operation not permitted

Is there any way to uninstall FaceTime?

Comment: I'm slightly hesitant to flag this as a duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/240632/how-to-remove-apple-system-apps because I think it's probably even harder to remove FaceTime than iTunes or Chess etc & possibly would have more serious consequences.

Comment: Do you want to ensure that FaceTime cannot be used? Because there are conceivably better methods for doing that. Or something else? The app, which is only 10Mb in size, is just a front end for a variety of APIs within the OS. You can even initiate FaceTime from Messages.app. So it may be possible to access FaceTime without the app itself.

Comment: My answer would be don’t uninstall system frameworks or apps. Perhaps there is a compelling reason for this request?

Comment: @Tetsujin I would expect it to be different than removing iTunes or Chess.

Comment: @benwiggy I want to remove the application called FaceTime.app.

Comment: @bmike I understand that it is developed and installed by Apple Inc. I'm interested in the steps necessary to remove it.

Comment: @BrianSpiering Yes, but why? Is it to prevent FaceTime being used, or just to save disk space? Knowing the reason might provide a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

You **do not** need to disable **System Integrity Protection** (SIP).

To delete the **FaceTime** app, do the following:

1. Backup **FaceTime.app** via **Time Machine** or making a **Zip** archive.

   - For the **Zip** archive, *right-click* it and select: **Compress "FaceTime"**
2. Shutdown your Mac.
3. Boot to **Recovery Mode**. Press **⌘R** when starting your Mac.
4. Open **Terminal** from the **Utilities** menu.
5. Run the following *compound command* adjusting **Macintosh HD** as necessary if you've modified the *default name* of the *primary startup volume*:

   ```
   rm -r "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Applications/FaceTime.app"; reboot
   ```
6. After rebooting from **Recovery Mode**, if you still have the **FaceTime** icon on the **Dock**, *right-click* it and select: **Options** > **Remove from Dock**

---

Note that while this does remove the **FaceTime.app**, it may/will reappear when **macOS** is updated/upgraded and will need to be deleted again.

If after having done this and you want to restore the **FaceTime** app, then restore it using **Time Machine**, if you backed it up in that manner, or if you created the **Zip** archive, it would have been created in the **/Applications** folder, if you moved it elsewhere, move it back and then do the following:

1. Shutdown your Mac.
2. Boot to **Recovery Mode**. Press **⌘R** when starting your Mac.
3. Open **Terminal** from the **Utilities** menu.
4. Run the following *compound command* adjusting **Macintosh HD** as necessary if you've modified the *default name* of the *primary startup volume*:

   ```
   cd "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Applications"; ../usr/bin/unzip FaceTime.zip; reboot
   ```